Drona and Kripa observing Kshatriya duty
In Udhyoga parva (05,137), we see Drona saying he has to fight, while observing Kshatriya duties.

taṃ cet putrāt priyataraṃ pratiyotsye dhanaṃjayam
kṣatradharmam anuṣṭhāya dhig astu kṣatrajīvikām
Alas, in observance of the Kshatriya duties, I shall have to fight even against that Dhananjaya who is dearer to me than my son. Fie on the Kshatriya profession.

Yes, Drona was teaching Kshtriya profession; he was eating food given by Dhritaratra... but he was still a Brahmana. How he can say he is observing Kshatriya duties? If Dhritarastra was feeding, thats any king would do to a brahmana; that doesn't make all brahmanas fed by the king to take weapon when the king goes to battlefield.
Kripa's case is even more peculiar. He, being kula guru, wasnt even doing anything like Drona. Him going to war is like Vasishtha joining Rama in battle against Ravana. Is it purely his affection to Drona?
It was never in question of them going to battlefield. Whenever war was discussed, Drona's name was always taken along with Bhishma.
I was struggling to find a meaningful justification in Mahabaratha. Did I miss something? Or any puranas explain they joined battlefield?

This question is similar to: Why did Drona and Kripa, who were Brahmanas, fight in the Mahabharata war? and Why did drona help the kauravas. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
